# Synchronize sending data to the server, whether there is internet or not in Flutter

Tags: flutter, http, dart, caching, dio

I am trying to add the temporal feature in my application so that if there is an Internet, the data is sent in the application, and in the absence of the Internet, I keep it and then send it in the event that there is Internet. What should I do about this thing and what is the preferred library to use http or dio

Comment: You can use the `shared preferences` package to store data you need to send when there is no internet. Then if the user comes online make a trigger that will send the stored data to the server. Use anyone `http` or `dio`

Comment: are you have any example please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i use dio_http_cache: plugin and it work with me but the best solutions is sqflite or hive